# While Installing Drupal manually I am getting error 500

Tags: drupal, installation, web-hosting, drupal-8

I am creating a sub-domain and on that I am trying to create Drupal website. (I am not able to create simple installation provided by many hosting companies , mostly due to I am trying to install on subdomain)
When trying to install Drupal Manually following [this](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/installing-drupal-7/step-4-run-the-installation-script#8) procedure,(stuck at this step 4) I am getting error HTTP 500 saying unable to handle this request.

Then I checked the error logs for more detail.

There I found PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Drupal\Component\Utility\OpCodeCache' not found in mysubdomain/install.php on line 37

I think install.php is unable to access the file OpCodeCache.php, because on commenting the code accessing OpCodeCache, I got another error, in error log saying "PHP Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface' not found in Subdomain Name/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 65"

I have given correct permissions (755 to directories, install.php and 644 to other files)

Can any one help me to sort out this problem any help will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable opcache on your  server. This article might help.

https://www.drupal.org/node/2623566

Not sure, if this works on a shared hosting.

Comment: Hi! Any idea how can I enable it on hosting server? Where can I found php.ini ?